# How to extract data from HTML websites?

Tags: java, html, automation, extract

I need to extract some text from a html based website. I have about 3000 URLs and need to extract a single line of text from their html. The data I need looks like this:

```
 <html xmlns:og="http://opengraphprotocol.org/schema/">
<head>
<title>Pink Floyd Live Audio Feeds</title>// the line i need
...
```

How can I automate this process? I am good at Java so a methodology using that language is preferred. Thanks!

Comment: Take a look at JSOUP to extract HTML content from a page.

Comment: Please have a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5468385/java-web-site-meta-data) question which I think may answer this.

Comment: Is it possible that title will be split into few lines like `<title>first line\n second line\n third line</title>`?

Comment: No, all are in a single line..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can read html text line by line and when you find `</title>` stop reading rest of page. Here is how this can be done (I assume that `<title>` and `</title>` are in the same line of HTML code as you pointed in comment)

```
public static String getTitle(String address) throws IOException {
    URL url = new URL(address);
    BufferedReader reader = null;
    try {
        reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(url.openStream()));

        String line = null;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            int start = line.indexOf("<title>");
            int end = line.indexOf("</title>");

            if (start != -1) {
                return line.substring(start + "<title>".length(), end);
            }
        }

        return "";
    } finally {
        if (reader != null)
            reader.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Sometimes, this is returning some other title present in the html instead of the main title which is at the top.. How can this be corrected?

Comment: @ankitrawat It will be hard to help you without example HTML code that can generate such problem. Could you give link to page that generate such behavior?

Comment: Nevermind, it was flawed logic on my part. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 4):

You can use [jsoup](http://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/example-list-links) which is a good Java library for working with real-world HTML.

Answer (score 0):

Iterate through your list of URLS and use `HttpURLConnection` to download the page. After you have all of the pages process the data to extract the information you need. [Here's the HttpURLConnection java doc page](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html)